# Carrierwave_Direct's direct_upload_form_for returns undefined method `model_name' for FileUploader:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, mongoid, carrierwave

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours now. When using carrierwave_direct's `direct_upload_form_for` in my view, it returns me this error:
[image]

**FileUploader Carrierwave Class:**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
end
```

**ManualFile Model:**

```
class ManualFile
  include Mongoid::Document
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

  field :name, :type => String
end
```

**UploadController:**

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
    def manual_new
        @uploader = ManualFile.new.file
        @uploader.success_action_redirect = upload_edit_path
    end

    def manual_edit
        @myfile = ManualFile.new(key: params[:key])
    end
end
```

**My View:**

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :file %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I tried to follow this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3). I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3, Mongoid 3 with carrierwave gems pointing to github master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `direct_upload_form_for` works best with ActiveRecord. To make it work (or at least not crash) with Mongoid, I added the following lines to my file uploader.

```
include ActiveModel::Conversion
 extend ActiveModel::Naming
```

So in your case :

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
    include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming
end
```